# Циклический сдвиг элементов массива влево на одну позицию

Tags: алгоритм, ruby

Такую задачу я нашел в одном сборнике задач по программированию на Ruby.
Во-первых, не совсем понятна суть задачи: сместить по индексам? Не трогать индексы, но сместить по значениям? Что делать с последним элементом?
Подскажите, как такое можно осуществить.
Пытался сделать так:

```
arr = Array.new(10) { rand(-10..10) }

puts "Original Array"
puts arr

arr.each_with_index do |val, i|
arr[i - 1] = val
end

arr.each_with_index do |val, i|
  puts "#{i}: #{val}"
end
```

Но это не дало нужного результата.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Такой метод есть в стандартной библиотеке [Array#rotate](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-rotate).

Если именно алгоритм, то `array.push(array.shift)` мне нравится, только надо проверить на 0 длину.

Comment: `array.shift` вернёт nil для пустого массива и всё сломается: `@2.2.2 :001 > [].shift` => `=> nil`.

Answer (score 1):

Ну путём руби это так будет выглядеть, вынимаем слева, т.е. из начала набора, и кладём сразу же в конец, т.е. добавляем справа:

```
array.push(array.shift)
```

Если нужно на сдвинуть на `n` элементов, то так:

```
n = 3
array.concat(array.shift(n))
```

ПС: А вообще вам правильно подсказали про метод `#rotate`.

Comment: И это надо сделать столько раз, какова длина массива?

Comment: А хотя нет, стоп, задача ведь просто сдвинуть один раз. То есть я правильно понимаю, что мне нужно из массива [1, 2, 3] получить просто [2, 3, 1]? @Малъ

Comment: @МатвейМамонов да, я обновил ответ

Comment: array.shift вернёт nil для пустого массива и всё сломается: @2.2.2 :001 > [].shift => => nil.

Answer (score 0):

На одну позицию просто: сохраняете значение левого элемента, затем слева направо элементу присваиваете значение следующего, а потом сохраненное значение - последнему.

Если циклический сдвиг на произвольное число элементов - тут тяжелее, надо делать три реверса - двух участков массива и всего массива целиком...

Comment: вот что получилось:
`# replace all - elements to the max value
startTime = Time.now
arr = Array.new(10) { rand(-10..10) }

puts "Original Array"
puts arr

first = arr.first

arr.each_with_index do |val, i|
  arr[i] = arr[i + 1]
end

arr[arr.length] = first

puts "new arr"
arr.each_with_index do |val, i|
  puts "#{i}: #{val}"
end

stopTime = Time.now

puts "Elapsed time"
puts stopTime - startTime
`
Результат:
Original Array
5
9
-3
5
-9
4
-5
-1
6
4
new arr
0: 9
1: -3
2: 5
3: -9
4: 4
5: -5
6: -1
7: 6
8: 4
9: 
10: 5
Elapsed time
0.000238901

Comment: @МатвейМамонов  Э, ребята, меня в это не тяните :) На C, pascal или там еще чем похожем напишу, тут только сувет могу дать, как, но не написать - как Чапаев в кино - "языкам не обучен!" :)

Comment: Вот на C: `int array[count];

int saved = array[0];
for(int i = 0; i < count-1; ++i)
    array[i] = array[i+1];

array[count-1] = saved;`